# Enabling/Disabling Fluvio Emitter during runtime (Unity 2D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I am having trouble trying to enable/disable the emitter during runtime. I would like to be able to click on the emitter and have it turn on/off accordingly. I know how to call `Input.GetMouseDown(0)`, but I do not know how to set the emitter. I tried using `gameObject.particleEmitter.enabled`, but that didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to use GameObject.GetComponent: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html

2) and then ParticleEmitter.enabled: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleEmitter-enabled.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on the emitter, first of all, the emitter game object has to have a `Collider` component. It can be 2d or 3d collider of various forms, depending on what exactly do you want. Then, the modern way of implement [`IPointerClickHandler`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html) interface, and ensure that you have an EventSystem and a relevant Raycaster (2d or 3d, depending on what collider are you using) present in the scene.